# Integral $\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x-k}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I need help solving the integral

$$\mathcal{I}(k)=\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x-k}\,dx$$

for $k>0$. The $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the Cauchy principal value. Mathematica has been unhelpful, but numerical tests show that it converges. I would also be happy with a series or asymptotic solution.

Edit: I attempt to solve for the asymptotic behaviour using Maxim's useful comment. Note that 
$$\mathcal{I}(k)\sim-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx$$ for large $k$. Then
$$\mathcal{I}(k)=-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x-k}\,dx+\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)=-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left[\frac{1}{x-k}+\frac{1}{k}\right]\,dx$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)=-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx+\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left[\frac{x/k}{x/k-1}\right]\,dx$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)=-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx-\frac{1}{k^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left[\frac{1}{1-x/k}\right]\,dx$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)\sim-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx-\frac{1}{k^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)^j\,dx$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)\sim-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^j\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{k^{j+1}}$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)\sim-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2j}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{k^{2j+1}}$$
$$\mathcal{I}(k)\sim-2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2j}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{k^{2j+1}}$$
Edit: This still doesn't work. My integrals diverge for $j>0$. Perhaps useful:
$$\tanh(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}2\frac{(-1)^{j}}{\pi^{2j+2}}\left(4^{j+1}-1\right)\zeta(2j+2)x^{2j+1}$$

Comment: If you're interested in the asymptotics for large $k$, $\mathcal I(k) \sim -\int_{\mathbb R} \tanh x^{-2} dx/k$ for $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very useful.

Comment: Might be related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform

Comment: Indeed, this is how I arrived at this integral. Maybe I will try some Fourier transforming. It looks like a convolution of my function with $1/x$.

Comment: Another solution by Sum: $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -\frac{4 k \sqrt{\pi } \left(-2+k^2 (\pi +2 n \pi )\right)}{\sqrt{1+2 n} \left(4+k^4 (\pi +2 n \pi )^2\right)}$

Comment: I am very interested in this result. Could you flesh this out with a few details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach, without analytical continuation.

\begin{gather}
  I=\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\tanh\frac{1}{x^2}}{x-k}\,dx=-\frac{1}{k}\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh t\,dt}{\sqrt{t}(t-k^{-2})}=-\frac{1}{k}\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(t-k^{-2})}+\frac{2}{k}\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(e^{2t}+1)(t-k^{-2})}=I_1+I_2
\end{gather}
Now, the contour your are going to use to take those two integrals is depicted in Fig.1

You can easily check that the integral along the small circle round point $t=k^{-2}$ vanishes (due to regular branch of $\sqrt{t}$ sign change).
This way you immediately see that $I_1=0$. Now you compute $I_2$. This is a typical $\zeta$-kernel type integral.  Denote:
\begin{gather}
   f_2(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}(e^{2t}+1)(t-k^{-2})},\quad \oint f_2(t)\,dt=2I_2=2\pi i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty
   \underset{t=\frac{i\pi}{2}(2n+1)}{\rm res}f_2(t)
\end{gather}
Next,
\begin{gather}
   \underset{t=\frac{i\pi}{2}(2n+1)}{{\rm res}}f_2(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3}}\frac{1}{2n+1+2ik^{-2}/\pi}(|2n+1|)^{-1/2}
   \begin{cases}
        e^{i\pi/4},\ \ n\geq0,\\
        e^{-i\pi /4}, n<0.
   \end{cases}
\end{gather}
And the whole thing is done:
\begin{gather}
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty\underset{t=\frac{i\pi}{2}(2n+1)}{{\rm res}}f_2(t)=e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2n+1+2ik^{-2}/\pi}(2n+1)^{-1/2}\\
   =e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l\Big(\frac{2i}{k^2\pi}\Big)^l\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{l+3/2}}=
   e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l\big[1-2^{l+3/2}\big]\Big(\frac{2i}{k^2\pi}\Big)^l\zeta(l+3/2)
\end{gather}
In the same manner you compute the sum over the lower poles:
\begin{gather}
   \sum_{{\rm lower\ poles}}= -\left(\sum_{{\rm upper\ poles}}\right)^*.
\end{gather}
Hence:
\begin{gather}
   2\pi i\sum_{{\rm all\ poles}}= 4\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\pi l}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\frac{2^l}{\pi^l k^{2l}}\zeta(l-3/2).
\end{gather}
And the initial integral reads:
\begin{gather}
 I=I_2 = 4\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\pi l}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\frac{2^l}{\pi^l k^{2l+1}}\zeta(l+3/2)\big[1-2^{l-3/2}\big].
\end{gather}

[image: Fig. 1]!

Comment: Another great answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The full series reads as follows:
$$
\mathcal{I}(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n+1} \left(\sqrt{2}-2^{n+2}\right) \zeta \left(-n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)k^{-2n-1}
$$
It is easy to check it numerically. If you are happy with this kind of result I can add more details later.

Comment: Please, do it ! Thanks i advance. Cheers :-)

Comment: Great, this is perfect. I am definitely interested in the details.